# R base fails to parse standard declared time format

Tags: r

This:

```
base::as.Date("07 Mar 2025", tryFormats ="%d %b %Y")
```

returns:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I'm using R 3.6.2 and sessioninfo returns:

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3

```
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_BE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_BE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_BE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_BE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.2
```

Comment: works for me `base::as.Date("07 Mar 2025", tryFormats ="%d %b %Y")` I am on R 3.6.1. I am not sure if anything changed.

Comment: What is the value of LC_TIME for your system?  If it's not English, as.Date might not understand Mar.  You can check with Sys.getlocale() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your locale, the month abbreviations are different.

In my UK locale:

```
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
[1] "English_United Kingdom.1252"
base::as.Date("07 Mar 2025", tryFormats ="%d %b %Y")
[1] "2025-03-07"
```

In a German-speaking Belgian locale:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","German_Belgium.1252")
[1] "German_Belgium.1252"
base::as.Date("07 Mar 2025", tryFormats ="%d %b %Y")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

base::as.Date("07 Mrz 2025", tryFormats ="%d %b %Y")
[1] "2025-03-07"
base::as.Date("07 März 2025", tryFormats ="%d %b %Y")
[1] "2025-03-07"
```

You could try switching to an English locale to interpret the data using `Sys.setlocale`. Note that the 1252 ones are Windows-specific, you would probably need to use something like `en_GB.UTF-8` in Linux.

Comment: oh, my, would not have found this in a week if there were no SO